# Adding custom headers to JqGrid Create/Edit/Delete methods

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I'm trying to use JqGrid with a WebAPI. To access the webAPI we need to set custom headers.For example:

```
headers: {
    'Username': 'Administrator'
},
```

I can do that via AJAX to load the grid. However, I want to take advantage of the create/edit/delete that JqGrid supports. The problem is that JqGrid does not seem to allow me to add headers to the call:

```
$("#btnCreate").click(function () {
   jQuery("#myGrid").jqGrid('editGridRow', "new", { reloadAfterSubmit: true, url: 'htp://localhost/colorfolder/insert' });
});
```

How do you add headers to the create?

I can't add headers to the load of the grid, I even tried extending the onclickSubmit but to no avail.

Here is the code:

```
<head>
    <title>htp://stackoverflow.com/questions/6831306/load-local-json-data-in-jqgrid-without-addjsonrows</title>
    <meta htp-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="htp://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.14/themes/redmond/jquery-ui.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="htp://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/jquery.jqGrid-4.1.2/css/ui.jqgrid.css" />

    <script src="js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/i18n/grid.locale-en.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.jqGrid.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $.jgrid.no_legacy_api = true;
        $.jgrid.useJSON = true;
    </script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function CallWebAPI() {
            jQuery.support.cors = true;
            var webAPIurl = "htp://localhost/colorfolder/list";

            $.ajax({
                url: webAPIurl,
                headers: {
                    'Username': 'Administrator'
                },
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                type: 'GET',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: "{}",
                success: function (data) {
                    GetDataFields(data);
                },
                error: function (x, y, z) {
                    alert(x + '\n' + y + '\n' + z);
                }
            });
        }
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var lastsel2

        function GetDataFields(data) {
            'use strict';
            var data = {
                "page": "1",
                "records": "3",
                "rows": data
            },
            grid = $("#myGrid");

            grid.jqGrid({
                colModel: [
                    { name: 'FolderID', index: 'FolderID', width: "200" },
                    { name: 'FolderDescription', index: 'FolderDescription', width: "105"}
                ],

                onSelectRow: function (id) {
                    if (id && id !== lastsel2) {
                        jQuery('#myGrid').jqGrid('restoreRow', lastsel2);
                        jQuery('#myGrid').jqGrid('editRow', id, true);
                        lastsel2 = id;
                    }
                },

                pager: '#myGridPageControls',
                datatype: "jsonstring",
                datastr: data,
                jsonReader: { repeatitems: false },
                rowNum: 25,
                viewrecords: true,
                multiselect: false,
                caption: "Folder",
                height: "auto",
                ignoreCase: true
            });

            $("#btnCreate").click(function () {
                jQuery("#myGrid").jqGrid('editGridRow', "new", { reloadAfterSubmit: true, url: 'htp://localhost/colorfolder/insert' });
            });
        }

        var grid = $("#myGrid");      // your jqGrid (the <table> element)
        var orgEditGridRow = grid.jqGrid.editGridRow; // save original function

        var folder = { "Params": "<Filters><FolderTypeID>1</FolderTypeID><FolderDescription>Test</FolderDescription></Filters>" };

        jQuery.support.cors = true;

        $.jgrid.extend({ 
            editGridRow: function (rowid, p) {
                $.extend(p, { // modify some parameters of editGridRow
                    onclickSubmit: function (formid) {
                        $.ajaxSetup({
                            headers: {
                                'Username': 'Administrator'
                            },
                            type: 'POST',
                            data: JSON.stringify(folder),
                            contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
                            success: function (data) {
                                alert("inserting");
                            },
                            error: function (x, y, z) {
                                alert(x + '\n' + y + '\n' + z);
                                var alerting = "alert";
                            }
                        });
                    }
                });
                orgEditGridRow.call(this, rowid, p);
            }
        });

        CallWebAPI();
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <table id="myGrid"><tr><td/></tr></table>
    <div id="myGridPageControls"></div>
    <input type="button" id="btnCreate" value="Create" />
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be as simple as on something like as an edit (there would be sperate calls for deletes, etc)

```
editData: { ValueName: ValueData },
```

Comment: That's to send data I believe. I'm trying to add a custom header to the HTTP request so validate against a service.

Comment: For example I'm adding a header on the CallWebAPI function:        headers: {
      'Username': 'Administrator'
}       I'm trying to do the same on the edit/create/delete calls native to JQgrid

Comment: Maybe I don't understand what you are trying to do.  Are you not looking to pass extra data to your controller? As in you want to include extra data inside the POST that goes out from your client?

Comment: No I'm trying to add an authentication header to when JQgrid access the webAPI 'htp://localhost/colorfolder/insert'. For instance Username : Administrator needs to be in the header call when it tries to access 'htp://localhost/colorfolder/insert', or else the webAPI will return unauthorized.

Comment: Sorry I'm not familiar with that technology, but couldn't you just check that inside in your controller 'htp://localhost/colorfolder/insert', check if the value was passed in there and return an error back to the grid.

Comment: Unfortunately no. You can only access the controller if the header is in place. Its part of the security. In order to access it the header has to be there :(